# Android alarm synced with clock

Tags: android, alarm

Is there a way to tack the Alarm to the minute (or hour etc.?)

I know how to set an alarm that runs every n milliseconds, but I'm unclear on how to set it so that it's tacked to the clock tick... meaning, I want to set an alarm for every 120,000ms (every other minute) but I want it invoked ON the minute (not somewhere in between minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the `RTC_WAKEUP` option when creating an Alarm.  [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) is the related document describing this process.